# Event-case management in while-loop

Tags: labview

If I put the blocks showed in the picture in a while-loop everything fail, fo example the stop button does not working!
Someone could explain to me how use events correctly?

[image]

thanks

Comment: Tangent I noted while looking at your diagram: you appear to not know about autoindexing For Loops. You don't need to wire the N terminal. Your Colors array has the size you need, so just right click on the loop tunnel and select "Enable Indexing". That will save you a chunk of +1 and -1 logic to try and compute that N terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not connected the timeout terminal.

How it always waits for an event and will not allow you to stop the loop. As it does not iterate, it waits.

To stop the loop you should specify Stop button Event, so your loop will iterate upon clicking on stop and you will be able to stop it. OR you can just specify timeout let say 100 ms and Loop will iterate on timeout case once every 100ms, even there is no event.

Comment: I have made edits to this answer that I hope get peer reviewed. Even once those edits are accepted, my overall answer is that the architecture you've shown above is not a good one. It will not scale well and couples too much together. Instead, have two parallel while loops... one only has the event structure with NO timeout; it enqueues the arrays of data into a Queue . The other while loop reads from the Queue to pull data and render it on command. Then you're not wasting processor cycles redrawing needlessly. Destroy the queue to stop the second loop.

Answer (score 5):

Also try to avoid coercion dots (small red dots near some blocks like add) the data type is changed dynamically (I32 to double) but it is not efficient and the convention in LabVIEW is to change the data type mostly manually.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers tell you how to patch your code so that your current architecture continues working. But that architecture is fundamentally flawed if your application gets larger -- you're going to waste lots of CPU redrawing needlessly and you're going to end up with lags in your UI. A proper LV separation of business logic from graphics logic would look like the image shown below. This image is a LV clip from LV 2015, meaning if you save the image to disk and then drop it directly onto LV 2015 or later, the code will just drop directly. Sorry, I don't have an earlier version of LV with me at the moment so I can't give you a clip for a previous version, but the code below should work all the way back to LV 6.1 (circa 2001a.d.) if you recode it. 
[image]